# How can I fetch the values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have following table name is sk_event:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| S.No |  ticket_id | event_name | sell_amount | coupon_code |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1  |     5      |    Airtel  |     450     |    ABC      |
|   2  |     5      |    Airtel  |     500     |    No Code  |
|   3  |     6      |    Airtel  |     250     |    XYZ      |
|   4  |     5      |    Airtel  |     450     |    ABC      |
|   5  |     6      |    Airtel  |     250     |    XYZ      |
|   6  |     5      |    Airtel  |     450     |    ABC      |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Second table i have which name is sk_ticket

```
|------------------------------------|
| S.No. | Ticket_name | ticket Price |
|   5   |     10 KM   |      500     |
|   6   |     5  KM   |      300     |
|------------------------------------|
```

I am using following SQL query :

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sk_event e  INNER JOIN sk_ticket t ON e.ticket_name = t.ticket_name GROUP BY t.ticket_name") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

This query is not giving me the result which I want. I want following answer which will be show in datatable bootstraps. I know how to use datatable bootstraps. I just want child row data.

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  #  | Ticket Name | base Price | Sell Price | Coupon Used | Total |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  +  |    10 KM    |    500     |     -      |      -      |   4   |
|     |    10 Km    |     -      |    450     |     ABC     |   3   |
|     |    10 Km    |     -      |    500     |   No Code   |   1   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  +  |     5 Km    |    300     |     -      |      -      |   2   |
|     |     5 Km    |     -      |    250     |     XYZ     |   2   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So, in the above there are two rows result which is indicate by + and every row have some child rows which bifurcate coupon wise data.

How can I show my data like the above table?

Answer (score 0):

Your tried query will not works because you have tried wrong join query, you should do inner join with primary key and foreign key instead of your tried way. Because joins can perform only with primary key and foreign keys.

You can try below query. Hope below query will work for you and you can get your required data.

```
select * from sk_event se inner join sk_ticket st on se.ticket_id = st.S.No.
```

Comment: Yes you right, i have used as you said but how can i show my child rows values. this query showing only + rows but i want child rows as well.

Comment: As you mentioned you will use datatable. So, i am suggesting you to use AJAX parameter of datatable to fetch your child row data.

Comment: Ok Good idea let me try this.

Comment: Sure you can :)